# Como devolver el promedio al sumar las variables anteriores DJango

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

Quisiera saber como sacar el promedio de las siguientes 4 variables, esas variables ya sacan sus respectivos promedios de cada campo, pero quiero regresar el promedio de esas 4

```
def promtotal(self):#funcion para promedio
        average = self.puntualidad.all().aggregate(Avg('puntualidad'))
        average1 = self.dominio_del_tema.all().aggregate(Avg('dominio_del_tema'))
        average2 = self.promedio.all().aggregate(Avg('promedio'))
        average3 = self.Dificultad_del_curso.all().aggregate(Avg('Dificultad_del_curso'))
        suma = sum(average + average1)
        #suma = self.puntualidad.all().aggregate(Avg('puntualidad')) 
        return average, average1, average2, average3, suma
```

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante sencillo calcular la media en Python. Para ello puedes hacer uso de la función *mean* dentro del paquete statistics. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
def promtotal(self):#funcion para promedio
        from statistics import mean
        average = self.puntualidad.all().aggregate(Avg('puntualidad'))
        average1 = self.dominio_del_tema.all().aggregate(Avg('dominio_del_tema'))
        average2 = self.promedio.all().aggregate(Avg('promedio'))
        average3 = self.Dificultad_del_curso.all().aggregate(Avg('Dificultad_del_curso'))
        return mean([average, average1, average2, average3])
```